# Unity Gravity script lowering FPS because of overlap sphere checking collision

Tags: unity3d

What are some ideas or ways that I can increase the efficiency of this gravity script because it is way to depending for what i want it for.

The game has a target at the center and there are objects far away all around the target and when gravity script is enabled I create an overlap sphere check which objects have a rigidbody and collision and pull them to target at a constant speed, but my FPS drops to the floor.

Would it be more efficient to have a script in each of these objects with a AddForce and direction towards target? Or any other ideas? Maybe something to change in this current script?

Am I right on the gravity script being too demanding because of the distance the gravity script is checking?

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour
{
private Rigidbody ownBody;
[HideInInspector]
public float maxVelocityOfInfluence;
private float rangeOfInfluence = 7000.0f;

private void OnEnable()
{
    if (ownBody == null)
    {
        ownBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Collider[] cols = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, rangeOfInfluence);
    List<Rigidbody> rbs = new List<Rigidbody>();

    foreach (Collider c in cols)
    {
        Rigidbody otherBody = c.attachedRigidbody;
        if (otherBody != null && otherBody != ownBody && !rbs.Contains(otherBody) && 
HasTagDownHierarchy(otherBody.transform, "Boat"))
        {
            rbs.Add(otherBody);

            Vector3 offset = transform.position - c.transform.position;
            otherBody.velocity = (offset.normalized * maxVelocityOfInfluence);
        }
    }
}

private static bool HasTagDownHierarchy(Transform transform, string tag)
{
    if (!transform)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (transform.CompareTag(tag))
    {
        return true;
    }

    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        if (HasTagDownHierarchy(child, tag))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating like crazy use `Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc`

dont do `List<Rigidbody> rbs = new List<Rigidbody>();`

Replace with o(1) lookup `HasTagDownHierarchy(otherBody.transform, "Boat")` also avoid tags. Use markup classes.

edit: With look up I mean, in *Boat* `Awake` method cache the Colliders in a look up `Dictionary<Collider, Boat>`

Comment: I will do what you say thank you! The thing is once objects reach target, new objects get spawned again.

Comment: What do I do instead of List<Rigidbody> ?

Comment: You should probably use a pool then. Use a hashmap instead of the List its o(1). clear it each iteration

Comment: okay so I created the `HashSet`, I added an `Add()` and `Remove()` on `Enable()` and `Disable()`, now how do I incorporate `Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc` and `Time.fixedDeltaTime`? Mind helping me out?

Comment: Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc takes an array that it fills with the overlapping colliers. Make sure to make it big enough so that it can always contain all collders that you can overlap. But not too big for memory. The integer returned from it is the actual number of found colliders

Comment: Okay so I have completed this, I have returned the actual number of found colliders but the problem is I have other objects in this scene that should not be collected by overlap

Comment: isn't it best to get all the colliders from the HashSet because that is only filled with the "boats" that I am looking for, how would I do this. This will terminate the need to use overlapsphere

Comment: wait what? I thought a boat was a spaceship and 7k meters radius was to capture all spaceships within this radius (like a black hole or something)? Or are 7k radius a way of making sure all boats in scene are captured? If you want all boats in scene just put them in a List<Boat> at wake/destroy or enable/disable if pooled. Iterate over this list

Comment: its like a blackhole but only for boats as they are the only enemies, i just realized I should just used your hashset/list idea to be faster not the overlapSphere. Performance should improve correct?

Comment: Yeah, but then it will affect all boats in scene. Not just the ones inside the sphere. So different result.